# Cannot update firebase tools from 3.19.1

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Prior to version 4.0.0 being released I had no problems with my app. I have been trying to update Firebase Tools since 3.19.3 was released and it will not work. It says that it updates without any errors but the tools are stuck on version 3.19.1. It is not updating.

After the release of 4.0.0 hosting no longer works. Cloud functions and Firestore are working without issue. I don't get any errors. It just doesn't work. I've been tying everything I can and searching all over forums for answers and nothing.

Hosting is not working. Static assets are not loading. It says that index.html cannot be found...but that is because there is no index.html because I am using express-handlebars templating engine. I have index.handlebars which was working fine before the release of firebase-tools version 4.0.0.

Still can't update firebase-tools to the latest version.

Comment: I am using express-handlebars as my templating engine.

Comment: Please edit your question to go into more detail about what exactly "no longer works".  What are you expecting that doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had firebase-tools installed in two different directories on my computer. The directory that was being updated was not the directory that my project was using. I'm still not sure how that happened but I uninstalled firebase and node and reinstalled them and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To update firebase-tools, just run this command in the terminal:

`curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash`

note: you must have `curl` installed.